# How can I access variable resolving of Eclipse run configurations for an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to extend the Sysdeo Tomcat Plugin to be capable of resolving variables like you can specify in run configurations for Java applications, e.g. `${workspace_loc}`.

I have tried to use this, but the resulting array has no contents:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getPathVariableManager().getPathVariableNames();
```

Using this one does not give me the wanted variables:

```
JavaCore.getClasspathVariableNames();
```

Further I search for the code doing the actual variable replacement in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `IStringVariableManager` to access variables such as ${workspace_loc}. You get the manager with:

```
IStringVariableManager manager = VariablesPlugin.getDefault().getStringVariableManager();
```

To process the variables in a string use:

```
String newString = manager.performStringSubstitution(string);
```

You can also use the `org.eclipse.core.variables.dynamicVariables` and `org.eclipse.core.variables.valueVariables` extension points to add new variables.